# Using Python's SMTP more than once in a daemon

Tags: python, smtp, smtplib

I've written a small Python daemon that receives mail from the local, network and sends it via an external mail provider. The problem is that if once a connection is established, I can send an email once, but not another. The following code shows the problem:

I connect the server like so:

```
>>> from smtplib import SMTP
>>> smtp = SMTP()
>>> smtp.connect('mail.gmx.net', 587)
(220, b'gmx.com (mrgmx003) Nemesis ESMTP Service ready')
>>> smtp.login('XXX', 'XXX')
(235, b'Authentication succeeded')
>>> smtp.sendmail('XXX', 'XXX', '')
{}
>>> smtp.quit()
(221, b'gmx.com Service closing transmission channel')
```

Everything works fine, the email is sent. But if I do the same thing later, I get an error "503 Bad sequence of commands". The connect still works:

```
>>> smtp.connect('mail.gmx.net', 587)
(220, b'gmx.com (mrgmx003) Nemesis ESMTP Service ready')
```

but neither this works:

```
>>> smtp.login('XXX', 'XXX')
(503, b'Bad sequence of commands')
```

nor this:

```
>>> smtp.sendmail('XXX', 'XXX', '')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.2/smtplib.py", line 749, in sendmail
    raise SMTPSenderRefused(code, resp, from_addr)
smtplib.SMTPSenderRefused: (503, b'Bad sequence of commands', 'XXX')
```

So, what's wrong here? If I do the whole thing again, starting with "smtp = SMTP()", everything works again. Shouldn't "smtp.quit()" reset the connection?

Thanks for all help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing `smtp.ehlo('XXX')` in the second session. Try adding it immediately after the `.connect()`. The `EHLO` or `HELO`, as the case may be, is implicitly sent in the first session, but not in the second. If you send it explicitly, then your example will work.

This is arguably a bug in the smtplib.

Comment: Thanks, it made the code actually work without having to reinstantiate SMTP. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It seems fairly clear that the author of this SMTP class did not intend for instances to be recycled after `quit()`. Create a new instance instead.

Comment: Okay, if this is not a bug, but a feature, I'm fine ;-) I just thought something with my code was wrong.